# Why did parseFrom() function hang using protobuf in java socket?

Tags: java, sockets, echo, protocol-buffers

I just want to create echo server/client using protobuf and java.

I tested with protobuf-java-2.4.1 and jdk1.7.

I wrote echo server code like below

```
// create server socket and accept for client connection.
// ...
link = servSock.accept();                       
Person person = Person.parseFrom(link.getInputStream()); // blocking position
person.writeTo(link.getOutputStream());
```

I think it is not necessary to note Person.proto.

The client code is only send Person object using socket input stream and receive echo Person object.

```
// socket connect code was omitted.
Person person = Person.newBuilder().setId(1).setName("zotiger").build();
person.writeTo(echoSocket.getOutputStream());
person = Person.parseFrom(echoSocket.getInputStream());
```

But server was blocked in parseFrom function when the server and client both run.

I found if i use writeDelimitedTo() and parseDelimitedFrom(), then that is ok. I don't understand why the writeTo() and parseFrom() function does not working.

Why did the server blocking in there?

Is it necessary to send some end signal from client side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you have to use `writeDelimitedTo()`/`parseDelimitedFrom()` is that otherwise protocol buffers may have no idea how much data it needs to read from the socket. That presents a problem (I say *may* because you could of course create a message with only fixed length fields that wouldn't require this ... but protocol buffers has to deal with both cases)

The `writeDelimitedTo()` method writes the length of the message to the `OutputStream` then the message itself. Its counterpart `parseDelimitedFrom()` reads the length, then the message.

You can use `writeTo()` and `pasrseFrom()` with streams but only if you want to write/read a single message and are closing the stream after writing. The reader will then get an EOF to indicate the end of the message (also the case when reading from a file that contains only a single message).

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it doesn't work. if i use writeDelimitedTo() and parseDelimitedFrom(), then that is ok. I don't understand why the writeTo() and parseFrom() function does not working.

Comment: See rewrite of answer. Duh ... sorry, just woke up ... need more coffee.

Comment: zotiger, A protocol buffer message does not have anything in it that indicates end of Message so it will keep trying to the message until end of file is reached. The writeDelimitedTo puts a length at the start of the Message so protocol buffers know exactly how lon the message is.

Comment: If I am sending my Protocol Buffer object from Python, then receiving it in Java over a TCP socket, what functions should I use on either end? It looks like Python doesn't have an equivalent to the functions you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Don't write your own Client/Server, ie. RPC solution. There is one here......https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-rpc-pro/ which has some nice features already for java.

Comment: Does it support ActionScript? I just want to use java server and ActionScript 3.0 socket client.

Comment: unfortunately not. Its java server, java client only currently. If you frame the wirepayload correctly from a client, it would be possible to port to another language  - but i dont have the time for going in this direction.